# Grails neo4j plugin issue

Tags: grails, neo4j

I am trying to use **2.0.0-M1** version of grails plugin for neo4j but when i try to save any entity,it is giving me error :

The instance was updated by another user while you were editing. Stacktrace follows: org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.OptimisticLockingException: The instance was updated by another user while you were editing at org.grails.datastore.gorm.neo4j.NodePendingUpdate.run(NodePendingUpdate.java:83)

and if i try to use **2.0.0-M2** version,i got error :

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.startsWith() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [jdbc:neo4j:instance:]

Also tell me if 2.0.0-M2 is supporting rest or not.

Please reply fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration has changed significantly from M1 to M2. Internally the plugin now uses the Neo4j JDBC driver. I didn't yet found enough time to update the docs, in the meantime refer to  https://github.com/sarmbruster/neo4jsample/blob/neo4j_2.0/grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy for a valid sample config.

The error you're mentioning seems to be caused by a incorrect configuration.

M2 is capable of working with remote database, just set `datasource.url="jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474/"`, see https://github.com/sarmbruster/neo4jsample/blob/neo4j_2.0/grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy#L13

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but i am still getting problem :java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService  i have also copied buildconfig.groovy as well as datasource.grrove from the sample project you provided me link for

Comment: i also tried for rest,project run successfully but when i tried to persist object like 
  long id = 5;
  Person person = new Person();
  //person.setId(id);
  person.setName("ankit");
  println person.save(flush:true);
again i am getting error : 
The instance was updated by another user while you were editing. Stacktrace follows:
org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.OptimisticLockingException: The instance was updated by another user while you were editing
 at org.grails.datastore.gorm.neo4j.NodePendingUpdate.run(NodePendingUpdate.java:85)

Comment: yes,ignore second comment,i got it working but first issue for embedded is still there.
BTW thank you for such a plugin